# qunit reset timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I created an interface to launch the qunit tests manually, but the qunit test timer start when  showing the interface, not when start the test.

example:

```
 var myFun = function (){
     test('/Services/Json/ContinentService/GetAll', function(){
         ok(ContinentBaseDto, 'ContinentBaseDto exists');
         ok(ContinentBaseDto.GetAll, 'ContinentBaseDto.GetAll exists');
         stop();
         $.when(ContinentBaseDto.GetAll()).then(function(data){
            start();
               ok(data, 'ContinentBaseDto returns something');
               ok($.isArray(data), 'ContinentBaseDto returns array');
               equal(5, data.length, 'ContinentBaseDto returns array with five elements (continents)');
         });
     });
  }
 $('#button').click(function(){
    myFun();
 });
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you could implement your own timer

```
var myFun = function (){
    var start = new Date().getTime(),  
     test('/Services/Json/ContinentService/GetAll', function(){
         ok(ContinentBaseDto, 'ContinentBaseDto exists');
         ok(ContinentBaseDto.GetAll, 'ContinentBaseDto.GetAll exists');
         stop();
         $.when(ContinentBaseDto.GetAll()).then(function(data){
            start();
               ok(data, 'ContinentBaseDto returns something');
               ok($.isArray(data), 'ContinentBaseDto returns array');
               equal(5, data.length, 'ContinentBaseDto returns array with five elements (continents)');
         });
    var diff = new Date().getTime() - start;
     });
```